# Getting transactions and time from Block Chain Info Api

Tags: mining-pools, blockchain.info

I want to fetch transactions for an address from the following api:

```
https://blockchain.info/address/$btc_address?format=json
```

The thing is understanding the json returned from the api, I don't understand which of them are the transaction and the time when that transaction took place.

Can any one help?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an online JSON viewer like http://jsonviewer.stack.hu (there are many others).

Just paste the return JSON into their text box and click the "viewer" tab. you will then see the JSON data in a formated expandable tree view, making it much easier to identify the transaction ids, times, and blockheights.

The transactions start under the [txs] tab in the tree.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I assume the time there represents the transaction time, but what about the amount of transaction that took place on that time, how do I know that?
I saw data under [prev_out] and other in [out], it is really confusing.

Comment: Maybe studying the bitcoin wiki a little will help you, since the things that confuse you are pretty trivial once you get how it all works. In any case, each transaction can have many inputs ([inputs]), and many outputs ([out]). the transaction itself happens at the time specified, included at the block specified. And finally, each input is, essentially, a previous output.